# SQL Server COUNT multiple tables returns WRONG RESULT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the tables:

**from Accounts AS acc**

```
AccountName
-------------
Account #1
Account #3
Account #2
```

**from Divisions as div joined with Accounts**

```
AccountName DivisionName
----------- ---------------------------
Account #1  Division TWO for Account #1
Account #1  Division ONE for Account #1
```

**from AccountSuppliers as acc_sup (a many-to-many join)**

```
AccountName SupplierName
----------- ------------
Account #1  Supplier #6
Account #1  Supplier #1
Account #1  Supplier #3
Account #2  Supplier #1
Account #2  Supplier #2
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    acc.AccountName,
    COUNT(div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,
    COUNT(acc_sup.AccountId) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM 
    Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN 
    Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN 
    AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY 
    acc.AccountName
```

And here is the result:

```
AccountName CountDivisions  CountSuppliers
----------- --------------- --------------
Account #1  6               6
Account #2  0               2
Account #3  0               0
```

Which SHOULD be:

```
AccountName CountDivisions  CountSuppliers
----------- --------------- --------------
Account #1  2               3
Account #2  0               2
Account #3  0               0
```

Note how adding the DISTINCT keyword ALSO produces a strange result:

```
SELECT 
    acc.AccountName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT acc_sup.AccountId) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM 
    Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN 
    Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN 
    AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY 
    acc.AccountName
```

produces:

```
AccountName CountDivisions  CountSuppliers
----------- --------------- --------------
Account #1  1               1
Account #2  0               1
Account #3  0               0
```

HUH? I'm probably overlooking something simple, but this result is clearly incorrect.  Could someone suggest the proper way for me to write this query to get the correct result?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint : `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` would help.

Comment: @YogeshSharma - No.  I tried adding DISTINCT to the COUNT aggregates.  I get a different result set, but it is also wrong.

Comment: please, add your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use distinct keyword in count statemetns

```
SELECT acc.AccountName,
COUNT(distinct div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,
COUNT(distinct acc_sup.AccountId) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY acc.AccountName
```

or More Resource efficient way:

```
 SELECT 
   acc.AccountName,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Division where div.AccountId = acc.Id) CountDivisions,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AccountSupplier WHERE acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id) AS CountSuppliers 
 FROM aCCOUNT AS acc
```

Comment: Simonare - - your first suggestion also produces a strange result set.  I edited by question to show that.  However, your SECOND suggestion worked perfectly.  That is the preferred solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @CCPony : This answer also shows what's wrong, `COUNT(distinct div.AccountId)` vs `div.AccountId = acc.Id` in the where clause of the sub-query - you were counting the Account ID not the identity value that uniquely identifies the row - which is why adding the Distinct keyword was producing a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `DISTINCT` where you want to count unique values:

```
SELECT acc.AccountName,
COUNT(DISTINCT div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,
COUNT(DISTINCT acc_sup.AccountId) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY acc.AccountName, div.AccountId, acc_sup.AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue within the query causing the incorrect result is that you asked to count the wrong field.

```
SELECT 
    acc.AccountName,
    COUNT(div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,
    COUNT(acc_sup.AccountId) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM 
    Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN 
    Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN 
    AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY 
    acc.AccountName
```

When the count is changed to be `COUNT(DISTINCT div.AccountId) AS CountDivisions,` - `div.AccountID` is the field being used in the join, so it would be an identical value for each row within the group - counting those distinct values would of course be just 1 no matter how many matched.

The count should be on a unique field within the child table, assuming you have an `ID` field it would be as follows:

```
SELECT 
    acc.AccountName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT div.Id) AS CountDivisions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT acc_sup.Id) AS CountSuppliers 
FROM 
    Account AS acc
LEFT JOIN 
    Division AS div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
LEFT JOIN 
    AccountSupplier AS acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)
GROUP BY 
    acc.AccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. You just missed the column you needed to count the aggregation from.

Based on your setup data, let's look at the data that we'll be working with from the given query. We want to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s because we want to count all of the `AccountName`s even if there aren't any `DivisionName`s or `SupplierName`s. We'll get `null` for those, which converts to a count of `0`.

So:

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Account acc
> LEFT JOIN Division div ON (div.AccountId = acc.Id)
> LEFT JOIN AccountSupplier acc_sup ON (acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id)  ;
> ```

Gives us:

> ```
> id | AccountName | accountID | DivisionName | accountID | SupplierName
> -: | :---------- | --------: | :----------- | --------: | :-----------
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div2         |         1 | Supplier6   
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div2         |         1 | Supplier1   
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div2         |         1 | Supplier3   
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div1         |         1 | Supplier6   
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div1         |         1 | Supplier1   
>  1 | Acct1       |         1 | Div1         |         1 | Supplier3   
>  2 | Acct2       |      null | null         |         2 | Supplier1   
>  2 | Acct2       |      null | null         |         2 | Supplier2   
>  3 | Acct3       |      null | null         |      null | null
> ```

With that, we can verify that our counts are working correctly, (*keeping in mind that `null` has some limitations in how math can be applied to it*).

With that, we can see that there are only two distinct `DivisionName`s for `Acct1` and none for the others. And 3 distinct `SupplierName`s for `Acct1`, 2 for `Acct2` and none for `Acct3`. That kinda gives us a plain-language explanation of what we need to do. We need distinct name for Divisions and Suppliers.

So:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     acc.AccountName,
>     COUNT(DISTINCT div.DivisionName) AS CountDivisions,
>     COUNT(DISTINCT acc_sup.SupplierName) AS CountSuppliers 
> FROM Account acc
> LEFT JOIN Division div ON div.AccountId = acc.Id
> LEFT JOIN AccountSupplier acc_sup ON acc_sup.AccountId = acc.Id
> GROUP BY acc.AccountName ;
> ```

This gives us the counts we were expecting:

> ```
> AccountName | CountDivisions | CountSuppliers
> :---------- | -------------: | -------------:
> Acct1       |              2 |              3
> Acct2       |              0 |              2
> Acct3       |              0 |              0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=db66c3dc6381d0c2a7e80a6c7d69ad6a)*

Comment: And again, I didn't push my submit button. Depending on the data you're working with and the indexes you have (and your SQL Server version), you may get different performance based on a pure `JOIN` with `DISTINCT` or using Simonare's correlated sub-query example. You'll want to test.